# How to simulate anchor link click

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'm trying to trigger a link click for .jquery.  Does someone know why the following doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div>
       <a id="google_link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">click to go to google</a>
    </div>
    <div id="google_link_proxy">click here to do the same as the link above</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">      
     $("#google_link_proxy").click(function(event){
         $("#google_link").click();
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.observe()` and `.fireEvent()`? Huh? Where did you learn jQuery? I'd suggest [this book](http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1933988355). The [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is also excellent as reference.

Comment: You should not edit your question to change the original meaning of it.

Comment: Why in this world are you adding the answers stuff to your question? This way we won't be to understand, what your issue was and what answer helped you!

Comment: @Afzaal,  The question doesn't have the answer.

Comment: You have already marked one question as answer brother. Have a look at the first answer. The one marked!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like your `$("google_link_proxy")` selector is off.  Try `$("#google_link_proxy")`.

You also need to close the observe call with `})`.

Those are the syntax errors with the code above though I don't think those functions are provided in jQuery by default.

Here is what I think you're after:

```
$("#google_link_proxy").click(function(event){
    window.open($("#google_link").attr('href'),'_blank')
});
```

Comment: this is what I ended up using.  i don't know why $("#...").click() wasn't working.  thanks

Comment: Hi, do you by any chance know if this is properly supported across all browsers?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is supported across all browsers.

Comment: There is a better way. Just do `$('#google_link')[0].click();`

Answer (score 48):

The jQuery method completely ignores `href`:

```
$('#google_link').click(); // ignores href!
```

The native DOM method does the right thing:

```
$('#google_link')[0].click();
```

This works regardless of whether the `href` is a URL, a fragment (e.g. `#blah`) or even a `javascript:`.

Comment: Yes! Or if you like that syntax better, use jQuery's `.get()` method: `$('#google_link').get(0).click();`

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer, along with @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson 's comment. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 21):

If you use jQuery and the native DOM, the anchor can be clicked

```
// insert an <a> into document and click it **natively**
// (.get(0) returns the DOM element)
$('<a id="fred99" />').attr('href', '#david').attr('target', '_blank')
.text('LINK').appendTo('body').get(0).click();

// now we've clicked, tidy up
$('#fred99').remove();
```

Comment: IMO, this is the true solution as calling click on an existing link to which you updated the href value via javascript does not open the url. Also, this will not be locked by a pop-up blocker since it doesn't use window.open. This solution works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("#google_link_proxy").click(
    function(){
        $("#google_link").click();
    }
);
```

fireEvent and observe is not part of jQuery API

Comment: The `.observe()` is also not part of jQuery API.

Comment: Edited it to have a better example. FYI: pop up blockers may block this.

Comment: Don't use `$('#google_link').click();`. Use `$('#google_link')[0].click();`, which uses the DOM-provided click method instead of the jQuery one.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your jQuery code wrapped in a *ready* block like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */});
```

This ensures scripts are fired *after* all the content and images are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('#google_link').click()
```