# How do I simulate a jQuery shake animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do some animation without Flash, I need a logo to load then shake before coming to a complete stop

I need it to happen on load (the shaking is a client request).

Right now, this works when you click it, but I need it to run automatically.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
      $(this).css({"position": "absolute"});
      for(var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
        $(this).animate({left: 43}, 10)
          .animate({left: 23}, 50)
          .animate({left: 23}, 10)
          .animate({left: 13}, 50)
          .animate({left: 43}, 50)
          .animate({left: 33}, 50)
          .animate({left: 43}, 50);
      }
    });
    return this;
  }

  $("#logo").click(function() {
    $(this).shake();
  });
});
```

The `#logo` element is the div that contains the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you search at all?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839363/simulating-a-click-in-jquery-javascript-on-a-link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786377/simulate-native-click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338161/jquery-simulate-a-a-href-link-click

Comment: Yes I did, but couldn't get it to work. Not a programmer, but got my question answered, thanks.

Comment: If your question was answered it's common courtesy on stack overflow to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
        this.each(function(i) {
            $(this).css({
                "position": "absolute"
            });
            for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: 43
                }, 10).animate({
                    left: 23
                }, 50).animate({
                    left: 23
                }, 10).animate({
                    left: 13
                }, 50).animate({
                    left: 43
                }, 50).animate({
                    left: 33
                }, 50).animate({
                    left: 43
                }, 50);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logo").shake();
    });
</script>​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to simulate a click, you can add this to your code:

```
$("#logo").click();
```

Anyway, I recommend you to use $(document).ready instead of window, as it will allow you to let the scripts just execute after the document has been loaded.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ $(document).ready(function(){ jQuery.fn.shake = function() { this.each(function(i) { $(this).css({ "position" : "absolute" }); for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) { $(this).animate({ left: 43 }, 10).animate({ left: 23 }, 50).animate({ left:23},10).animate({ left: 13 }, 50).animate({ left: 43 }, 50).animate({ left: 33 },50).animate({ left: 43 }, 50); } }); return this; } $("#logo").click(function() { $(this).shake(); }); });//]]> </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, where exactly would I add that line?

Comment: I would edit your code like this http://pastebin.com/VEirp2ms

If you want, you could use @invertedSpear solution, by just using $("#logo").shake(); instead of click() :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `$("#logo").shake()` work at the end of your load function?

Instead of using:

```
$("#logo").click(function() {
  $(this).shake();
});
```

Use:

```
$("#logo").shake();
```

You don't have to add an `onclick` event listener and simulate a click, you can just fire that function directly instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, would I swap that in place of something in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should actually call `$('#logo').shake();` but you can also do `$('#logo').trigger('click');`

Check out the documentation for the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without clicking on the div , why are you having that click handler. You can do it when the page loads like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){

        jQuery.fn.shake = function() {
            this.each(function(i) {
            $(this).css({ "position" : "absolute" });
            for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            $(this).animate({ left: 43 }, 10).animate({ left: 23 }, 50).animate({ left:23},10).animate({ left: 13 }, 50).animate({ left: 43 }, 50).animate({ left: 33 },50).animate({ left: 43 }, 50);
                }
            });
            return this;
            }

        $(this).shake();
});//]]>  

</script>
```